Can vacuously true statements be proved using proof by contradiction?
I'd always thought that it's valid to prove vacuously true statements using proof by contradiction, but now I'm not so sure.
For example, to prove the vacuously true statement $$\forall (x \in \emptyset)\; x + 1 = 0,$$ I assume for the sake of contradiction that $$\exists (x \in \emptyset)\;x + 1 \neq 0.$$ This contradicts $x \notin \emptyset$ for all objects $x.$
But the property $x + 1 \neq 0$ does not make sense for any arbitrary object $x$ in $\emptyset$, does it? (Refer to my confusion regarding properties only being defined for certain sets of objects.) Is there a flaw in my reasoning?

Your thinking is correct in this example and the proof by contradiction works.

In my other question, I was under the impression that properties were only defined for a certain set of objects hence my confusion whether the property $x + 1 \neq 0$ was defined for the object $x$ in $\emptyset$ which I assume to exist in the proof by contradiction.

Not sure whether I am overthinking this or have some gross misunderstanding of logic.

Hi, welcome to Math SE. "There exists an $x$ in $\emptyset$ for which this property that might not always make sense is applicable" is equivalent to "There exists an $x$ in $\emptyset$ for which this property makes sense & is applicable", which is clearly false as no $x$ exists in $\emptyset$.

I see now. It seems like the linked question addresses your concern here. I'd describe the situation as: Before we can talk about proving the statement, we should check that it is well-formed in the sense that symbols like $+$ are not "evaluated on" operands on which they are undefined. In your example, we can see that the truth value of the statement does not depend on any values of +, so the domain of definition of + is irrelevant. The statement is well-formed (in this sense) for the same reason it is vacuously true.

Mathematical writing can be a little informal in this way, requiring the reader to do some work to see why an expression makes sense. If you were formalizing this statement for a computer proof assistant, you might need to explicitly give $x$ a numeric type before writing $x+1$.

@J.G. Hmm but then couldn't you argue that that a statement like $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, \det(x) = 0$ is true since using proof by contradiction, we assume $\exists x \in \mathbb{R}$ s.t. $\det(x) \neq 0$ which is 'false' because there does not exist an $x$ in $\mathbb{R}$ s.t. the property $\det(x) \neq 0$ is applicable (since determinant is not defined for real numbers). But then you could similarly argue that the statement $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, \det(x) = 0$ is also false. What is the issue here? Is it because the statement does not have a truth value to begin with?

@Karl could you clarify what you mean by ' the truth value of the statement does not depend on any values of +'?

And if a statement like $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, \det(x) = 0$ does not have a truth value then why does a statement like $\forall x \in \emptyset, \det(x) = 0$ have a truth value?

The negation of $\det x=0$ is "$\det x$ doesn't exist or does but isn't zero", which is true of some (in fact all) $x\in\Bbb R$, so you can't force the contradiction. But it's not true of some $x$ in $\emptyset$, the only set for which all doesn't imply some.

@J.G. Does that mean that properties like $x + 1 = 0$ actually pertain to every mathematical object $x$ and evaluate to true if the property actually pertains to $x$ and moreover $x + 1 = 0$?

If you want proof by contradiction's $\all\leftrightarrow\exists$ switching to work, you need the law of the excluded middle, so $x+1=0$ can be true or false but nothing else. I can understand why someone wouldn't subscribe to such an assignment of truth values; but if you do, the problem you ask about never arises.

By "the truth value of the statement does not depend on any values of +" I mean that if we assume + is defined on all inputs (to eliminate doubt as to whether the statement has a truth value) then the statement is true regardless of how + is defined.

I'd also add that in practice in mathematical writing we avoid the kinds of "type errors" you're asking about, so this isn't an issue. In a context where the language is being formally studied, we can (if necessary/convenient) assume symbols are defined to take some dummy value like $\emptyset$ on inputs outside their intended domains.

"But the property x+1≠0 does not make sense for any arbitrary object x in ∅, does it? "  Why wouldn't it?  It doesn't matter if it's never true or wouldn't make sense for anything that hypothetically exists.  "All unicorns have no horns" is a perfectly true statement.

Proof By Contradiction has this general template :
We want to Prove $P$
We assume the negation : $\lnot P$
We then derive some falsity [[ Eg1 "$\lnot \lnot P$" : Eg2 "$1 = 0$" : Eg3 "$\sqrt{2}$ is rational" : Eg4 "$8$ is irrational" ]]
Hence we conclude that the assumption was wrong
Hence the negation of the assumption is true : $\lnot [ \lnot P ] \equiv [ P ]$ is true
In OP Case , that template works :
We want to Prove : $P \equiv [ \forall x \in \emptyset, x + 1 = 0 ]$
We assume the negation : $\lnot [\forall x \in \emptyset, x + 1 = 0]$
That is : $\exists x \in \emptyset, \lnot [x + 1 = 0]$
That is : $\exists x \in \emptyset, [x + 1 \not = 0]$
That is a falsity : there is no $\exists x \in \emptyset$
Hence we conclude that the assumption was wrong
Hence the negation of the assumption is true : $\lnot [ \lnot P ] \equiv [ P ]$ is true
Proof By Contradiction work out well here !!

Do you mean "8 is irrational"?

Nice Catch of my typo , @Earthliŋ , I have changed it.

It is the same answer as in the other post: for the statement to be false, there has to be an $x\in\emptyset$ such that $x+1$ makes sense and $x+1\neq0$. But there is no element at all in $\emptyset$, consequently the statement is true.
Hope this helps. :)


Can vacuously true statements be proved using proof by contradiction?

Yes. The Principle of Vacuous Truth states that for any propositions $A$ and $B$, we have:
$~~~~~~A \implies ( \neg A \implies B)~~~$ (regardless of the truth value of $B$)
The truth table: $^1$

We can also prove this using a form of natural deduction and proof by contradiction (lines 3-5) as follows: $^2$

In your example, we have $A ~\equiv ~ x \notin \emptyset~$ and $~B ~\equiv ~ x+1 =0~$ obtaining, as required:
$x\notin \emptyset \implies (x\in \emptyset \implies x+1=0)$


Plain text versions:
1 Truth table:
A B A=>(~A=>B)
T T T
T F T
F T T
F F T
2 Proof:
1   A
    Premise

    2   ~A
        Premise

        Suppose to the contrary...

        3   ~B
            Premise

        Obtain the contradiction...

        4   A & ~A
            Join, 1, 2

    By contradiction...

    5   ~~B
        Conclusion, 3

    6   B
        Rem DNeg, 5

7   ~A => B
    Conclusion, 2

8   A => [~A => B]
Conclusion, 1


$$\exists (x \in \emptyset)\;x + 1 \neq 0.\tag1$$
But the property $x + 1 \neq 0$ does not make sense for any arbitrary object $x$ in $\emptyset$, does it?

I can't exactly figure out what you mean, but assumption $(1)$ is both well-formed and well-defined, and simply (albeit falsely) asserts that “some object in the empty set doesn't equal $0$ when added to $1.\text”$ It implies that some object is a member of the empty set $(\exists x\,x\in\emptyset).$ Since no object is in fact a member of the empty set (or: $\forall x\,x\not\in\emptyset),$ we have a contradiction. This proves the given statement $\;\forall (x \in \emptyset)\; x + 1 = 0,\tag0$ which by definition is vacuously true (and so doesn't require any proof in the first place).
I guess the point is that the predicate $x + 1 \neq 0\tag*{}$ is well-defined on $\emptyset.$
